# How can I resolve react native building problem in windows

Tags: react-native

I am using windows 10

I tried `react-native run-android` and get below error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!
```

Comment: As the error says, no device found. Please check you have enabled usb debugging before building the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try to describe your problem next time together with actions you took that might have caused the error. Your question title is grammatically incorrect. I don't even know if you are aware you must have a simulator running in order to run your app on device. So launch the simulator from android studio and then try to run the app. If this won't work you can try all the solutions mentioned here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3091 . Cheers.